# Neo4j count relationships of each type for given node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want to count the relationships for each type of a given start node. I have constructed two possible queries to achieve that, but I don't know which one is going to be more efficient when dealing with lots of relationships.

1. Cypher only query with `count()`

```sql
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 0
CALL {
    WITH n
    MATCH (n)<-[r]-()
    RETURN '<'+TYPE(r) AS type, COUNT(r) AS count
UNION ALL 
    WITH n
    MATCH (n)-[r]->()
    RETURN TYPE(r)+'>' AS type, COUNT(r) AS count
}
RETURN type, count
```

Result:

```
╒════════════╤═════╕
│type        │count│
╞════════════╪═════╡
│"<ACTED_IN" │5    │
├────────────┼─────┤
│"<PRODUCED" │1    │
├────────────┼─────┤
│"<DIRECTED" │2    │
└────────────┴─────┘
```

2. Cypher + APOC `apoc.node.relationship.types()` and `type, apoc.node.degree.[in|out]()`

```sql
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 0
WITH n, apoc.node.relationship.types(n) AS types
CALL {
    WITH n, types
    UNWIND types as type
    RETURN '<'+type AS type, apoc.node.degree.in(n, type) as count
UNION ALL 
    WITH n, types
    UNWIND types as type
    RETURN type+'>' AS type, apoc.node.degree.out(n, type) as count
}
RETURN type, count
```

Result:

```
╒════════════╤═════╕
│type        │count│
╞════════════╪═════╡
│"<ACTED_IN" │5    │
├────────────┼─────┤
│"<DIRECTED" │2    │
├────────────┼─────┤
│"<PRODUCED" │1    │
├────────────┼─────┤
│"ACTED_IN>" │0    │
├────────────┼─────┤
│"DIRECTED>" │0    │
├────────────┼─────┤
│"PRODUCED>" │0    │
└────────────┴─────┘
```

The second query returns rows for empty relationship types, but this can be neglected.

I can only profile the first cypher-only query, because custom procedures like APOC can't be profiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a faster approach that also fixes a potential problem in your current queries. If `n` has any self-relationships (relationships that start/end at `n`), then such relationships would be counted twice (as both inbound and outbound relationships). In other words, the sum of the counts could be greater than the actual number of relationships.

This query should be fast and also solve the self-relationship problem:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-() WHERE id(n) = 0
RETURN
  CASE n WHEN ENDNODE(r) THEN '<' ELSE '' END +
  TYPE(r) +
  CASE n WHEN STARTNODE(r) THEN '>' ELSE '' END AS type,
  COUNT(*) AS count
```

An inbound `REL` relationship would be represented as `<REL`, an outbound one as `REL>`, and a self-relationship as `<REL>`. And the sum of the counts would equal the actual number of relationships.

##### Including endnode labels

Here is a slightly altered query that returns a count of each distinct combination of type and end node labels (a node can have multiple labels):

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE id(n) = 0
RETURN
  CASE n WHEN ENDNODE(r) THEN '<' ELSE '' END +
  TYPE(r) +
  CASE n WHEN STARTNODE(r) THEN '>' ELSE '' END AS type,
  LABELS(m) AS endNodeLabels,
  COUNT(*) AS count
```

Reading how [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) work will help you understand these 2 queries.

Comment: Thanks that's great! One more question: I assume it's not easily possible to count the distinct _relationship type + end node label_ for a given start node?

Comment: That is very easy. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're only counting relationships for a single node, either version will take milliseconds, so performance isn't relevant. Only where counts were being done for many nodes would you consider it. In any case, without profiling, the best way would be to actually measure it.

I compared the following Cypher and APOC versions for different numbers of relationships (the actual `MATCH` double counts, but that doesn't matter for this):

**Cypher**

```sql
MATCH (n)-[r]-()
RETURN 
  CASE 
    WHEN (startNode(r) = n) THEN type(r) + '>' 
    ELSE '<' + type(r)
  END AS type, 
  count(r) AS count
```

**APOC**

```sql
MATCH (n)
CALL {
    WITH n
    WITH n, apoc.node.relationship.types(n) AS types
    CALL {
        WITH n, types
        UNWIND types as type
        RETURN '<'+type AS type, apoc.node.degree.in(n, type) as count
    UNION ALL 
        WITH n, types
        UNWIND types as type
        RETURN type+'>' AS type, apoc.node.degree.out(n, type) as count
    }
    RETURN type, count
}
RETURN type, sum(count)
```

Here is a comparison (based on running the DB locally):

[image]

There may be a more efficient version for the APOC query, but in any case, the Cypher here is faster.

Comment: Thank you for this! Did you use any special tool for this measurement?

Comment: No. I just used Cypher to clean out the DB and set up random relationships for different # of relationships, and then took best of 5 runs for each.

Comment: My Cypher answer is the same as the accepted, BTW 

Comment: APOC calls invlove an overhead. Writing more complicated Cypher to replace an APOC call can improve performance.

Comment: @FinbarGood you're right and honestly, I wasn't sure which answer to accept. I decided for the other answer, because it explained a possible issue in my query and answered my follow-up question. But yours was as good as the other.